# django admin panel date timedelta filtering

Tags: python, django

I'm using this filter:

```
late_borrowings = Borrowing.objects.filter(returned=False).filter(
    borrow_date__lte=datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=15))
```

How can I do it in django admin panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a simple filter that filters depending on the value:

```
class StatusFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'Status'
    parameter_name = 'Status'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (('late', 'Late'),)

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        value = self.value()
        if value == 'late':
            return queryset.filter(returned=False).filter(
                borrow_date__lte=datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=15)
            )
        return queryset
```

and then register the filter in the admin with:

```
@admin.register(Borrowing)
class BorrowingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # …
    list_filter = (StatusFilter,)
```